# R Optimization: Pass value from function to gradient with each iteration

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a function that I am optimizing using the `optimx` function in R (I'm also open to using `optim`, since I'm not sure it will make a difference for what I'm trying to do). I have a gradient that I am passing to `optimx` for (hopefully) faster convergence compared to not using a gradient. Both the function and the gradient use many of the same quantities that are computed from each new parameter set. One of these quantities in particular is very computationally costly, and it's redundant to have to compute this quantity twice for each iteration - once for the function, and again for the gradient. I'm trying to find a way to compute this quantity once, then pass it to the function and the gradient.

So here is what I am doing. So far this works, but it is inefficient:

```
optfunc<-function(paramvec){
    quant1<-costlyfunction(paramvec) 
    #costlyfunction is a separate function that takes a while to run

    loglikelihood<-sum(quant1)**2 
    #not really squared, but the log likelihood uses quant1 in its calculation

    return(loglikelihood)
}

optgr<-function(paramvec){
    quant1<-costlyfunction(paramvec)
    mygrad<-sum(quant1) #again not the real formula, just for illustration
    return(mygrad)
}

optimx(par=paramvec,fn=optfunc,gr=optgr,method="BFGS")
```

I am trying to find a way to calculate `quant1` only once with each iteration of `optimx`. It seems the first step would be to combine `fn` and `gr` into a single function. I thought the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046950/r-optimization-passing-objective-and-gradient-function-arguments-as-list) may help me, and so I recoded the optimization as:

```
optfngr<-function(){
    quant1<-costlyfunction(paramvec)
    optfunc<-function(paramvec){
        loglikelihood<-sum(quant1)**2
        return(loglikelihood)
    }
    optgr<-function(paramvec){
        mygrad<-sum(quant1)
        return(mygrad)
    }
    return(list(fn = optfunc, gr = optgr))
}

do.call(optimx, c(list(par=paramvec,method="BFGS",optfngr() )))
```

Here, I receive the error: "Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters." Of course, there are obvious problems with my code here. So, I'm thinking answering any or all of the following questions may shed some light:

1. I passed `paramvec` as the only arguments to `optfunc` and `optgr` so that `optimx` knows that `paramvec` is what needs to be iterated over. However, I don't know how to pass `quant1` to `optfunc` and `optgr`. Is it true that if I try to pass `quant1`, then `optimx` will not properly identify the parameter vector?
2. I wrapped `optfunc` and `optgr` into one function, so that the quantity `quant1` will exist in the same function space as both functions. Perhaps I can avoid this if I can find a way to return `quant1` from `optfunc`, and then pass it to `optgr`. Is this possible? I'm thinking it's not, since the documentation for `optimx` is pretty clear that the function needs to return a scalar.
3. I'm aware that I might be able to use the dots arguments to `optimx` as extra parameter arguments, but I understand that these are for fixed parameters, and not arguments that will change with each iteration. Unless there is also a way to manipulate this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One simple approach: keep track of the x vector. If changed then recompute intermediate results.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit? Is x vector the parameters that are changing? What are the "intermediate results"?

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is close to what you want, but not quite right.  You want to call `costlyfunction(paramvec)` from within `optfn(paramvec)` or `optgr(paramvec)`, but only when `paramvec` has changed.  Then you want to save its value in the enclosing frame, as well as the value of `paramvec` that was used to do it.  That is, something like this:

```
optfngr<-function(){
    quant1 <- NULL
    prevparam <- NULL

    updatecostly <- function(paramvec) {
      if (!identical(paramvec, prevparam)) {
        quant1 <<- costlyfunction(paramvec)
        prevparam <<- paramvec
      }
    }
    optfunc<-function(paramvec){
        updatecostly(paramvec)
        loglikelihood<-sum(quant1)**2
        return(loglikelihood)
    }
    optgr<-function(paramvec){
        updatecostly(paramvec)
        mygrad<-sum(quant1)
        return(mygrad)
    }
    return(list(fn = optfunc, gr = optgr))
}

do.call(optimx, c(list(par=paramvec,method="BFGS"),optfngr() ))
```

I used `<<-` to make assignments to the enclosing frame, and fixed up your `do.call` second argument.

Doing this is called "memoization" (or "memoisation" in some locales; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), and there's a package called `memoise` that does it. It keeps track of lots of (or all of?) the previous results of calls to `costlyfunction`, so would be especially good if `paramvec` only takes on a small number of values.  But I think it won't be so good in your situation because you'll likely only make a small number of repeated calls to `costlyfunction` and then never use the same `paramvec` again.